# GDM doesn't start and desktop looks weird after reinstalling GNOME and the Nvidia driver

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gdm

So, there was a problem before with display so i reinstall gnome and nvidia graphic driver;
It seems like the gdm wasn't reinstalled properly as ubuntu doesn't start;
It holds at this moment:

[image]

The gnome GUI doesn't load correctly as well. I started it like:
`startx` from terminal;

The GUI looks like this:

[image]

As you may see from above image there's no bar for menu and application;

How can i fix it?

Info from xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 290.10  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-07.nvidia.com)  Wed Nov 16 20:32:22 PST 2011

Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier     "Layout0"
   Screen      0  "Screen0"
   InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
   InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   # generated from default
   Identifier     "Mouse0"
   Driver         "mouse"
   Option         "Protocol" "auto"
   Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
   Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
   Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about your nvidia driver. Ubuntu failed to load unity. That's means your nvidia driver is not working correctly. What is your nvidia's specification and what driver do you use?

Comment: I've added /etc/X11/xorg.conf info; How can switch from unity to ubuntu classic via terminal?

Comment: Shouldn't greeter load at least, if it's all about nvidia driver?<br />
I've make lightdm-greeter the default one and ubuntu loaded. Thank you. I'll try to make gdm start then.

Comment: backup your /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Then delete it. Ubuntu will automatically select best driver. To start login page: sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop   THEN sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start

Comment: So, the problem wasn't really in nvidia driver, just in me. Some how i mess to install gnome, so lightdm loaded instead when `startx` and ubuntu doesn't start properly because gdm's greeter was used (not lightdm's one).